# How to properly run virtualenv via .sh run script (django)

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv

I am having an issue via an apache Nearly Free Speech server (I have been following the NFS guide via this link: https://blog.nearlyfreespeech.net/2014/11/17/how-to-django-on-nearlyfreespeech-net/.  I have created a run-django.sh file to properly run the application which also opens a virtualenv (I have named the folder 'venv').  These are the contents of my run-django.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
. venv/bin/activate
exec python3 manage.py runserver
```

On the current step of the guide I am attempting to run the run-django.sh as follows:

```
[questionanswer /home/protected]$ ls
question_answer run-django.sh   venv
[questionanswer /home/protected]$ cd question_answer/
[questionanswer /home/protected/question_answer]$ ../run-django.sh
.: cannot open bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

How is this not detecting my directory of 'venv/bin/activate' ?

Comment: It may be a good idea to use the full path to your virtualenv. Instead of `. venv/bin/activate` try using `/home/protected/venv/bin/activate`.

Comment: thank you that is what i was looking for!